# Agregar valor a una propiedad vacía o nula en javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Creo el siguiente objeto:

```
const obj = {
               type: [],
               status: [2]
            }
```

Necesito agregarle `0` en caso de que una propiedad se encuentre nula o vacía, cómo puedo hacerlo?

La idea es que quede como se muestra a continuación:

```
const obj = {
               type: [0],
               status: [2]
            }
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

si siempre estarán presentes esas propiedades `type` y `status` puedes realizarlo de varias maneras.

Esta es una:

```js
for(const prop of ['status','type']){
  if(obj[props] === null || !obj[props].length){
    obj[props] = [0];
  }
}
```

El [Método entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) te servirá si tienes que validar muchas propiedades

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, funciona muy bien!

Answer (score 2):

No se si he entendido muy bien tu pregunta pero creo que quieres hacer algo así. Estaría bien que pusieras un poco de contexto a la pregunta para saber que estas haciendo y poder ayudarte mejor. Pero con lo que has puesto, yo lo resolvería de esta manera. Saludos

```
     const obj = {
           type: [],
           status: [2]
        } 



if(obj.type== ""){
    obj.type=0;
}       

        alert(obj.type);
```

Comment: funcionó, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Partimos de que quieres agregar 0 a tu propiedad `obj.type` la cual es un array, pero lo agregamos **solo si una propiedad se encuentre nula o vaciá**:
Aquí usamos un `if` el cual evaluá el tipo de dato primitivo *Boolean* y ejecutara el código en caso de que el dato evaluado convertido a *Boolean* devuelva **true**.
Ahora tenemos ciertos datos o valores que siempre devuelven **false** cuando se castean a *Boolean*:

```javascript
DATO1=0
DATO2=-0
DATO3=null
DATO4=false
DATO5=NaN
DATO6=undefined
DATO7=""
/*Cada uno de estos valores lo pasamos por Boolean
y siempre tendremos como valor de retorno un false*/
Boolean(DATO1) //---> false
```

Si tu propiedad toma como valor alguno de estos valores entonces el bloque de código que corresponde al `if` no se ejecutara:

```
const obj = {
               type: [],
               status: [2]
            }

let propiedad=''
if(propiedad)
{
    console.log("Esto no se ejecutara")
}
else
{
    console.log("Esto si se ejecutara")
    //Aqui aprovechamos para añadir un 0 a nuestro array
    obj.type.push(0)
}
console.log(obj)
```

Pero existe una forma mas limpia de hacerlo y es negando a propiedad, es decir si tu propiedad retorna **false**(por que tiene como valor algo que retorna false) entonces la negamos haciendo que esta devuelva **true**:

```
const obj = {
    type: [],
    status: [2]
}
        
let propiedad=false
if(! propiedad)
{
    obj.type.push(0)
}
console.log(obj)
```